# jquery counter/uncounter function

Tags: jquery, counter

I'm working on a function where users can click a star and a counter will increase and the word Unlike will appear. Then, if users click on Unlike the counter decreases and the word Unlike disappears. So far, it works.

The challenge is this: I want each user to only be able to click once (that's working now) **but I want them to be able to click the star again IF they have already clicked the Unlike phrase** (which would have removed the number from the counter). (Code and jsfiddle below).

**HTML**

```
<span href="" class="star">Star</span>&nbsp;<span class="star_number"></span> 
&#183;&nbsp;<span class="unstar">Unlike</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.unstar').hide();
    var count1=0;

    $('.star').one("click", function() { 
        count1++;
    $('.unstar').show();

    $('.star_number').html(count1);
    });

    $('.unstar').one("click", function() { 
        count1--;
    $('.unstar').hide();

    $('.star_number').html(count1);
    });

 });
```

Also, here's the js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j5qAs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `one` to `bind` and add a check for `:visible` or `:hidden`

```
$(function(){
    $('.unstar').hide();
    var count1=0;

    $('.star').bind("click", function() { 
        if ($('.unstar').is(':hidden')) {
            count1++;
            $('.unstar').show();
            $('.star_number').html(count1);
        }
    });

    $('.unstar').bind("click", function() { 
        count1--;
        $('.unstar').hide();
        $('.star_number').html(count1);
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5qAs/3/

Answer (score 1):

I think below should do the trick, If I understood your question correctly,

I used `:visible` instead of `count` because I assumed that the count will be returned from server and it may not be 1 or 0.. it will be > 1.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/j5qAs/2/) here

```
$(function(){
    $('.unstar').hide();
    var count1=0;

    $('.star').bind("click", function() {        // <-- changed to bind
        if ($('.unstar').is(':visible')) return; // <-- added
        count1++;
        $('.unstar').show();

        $('.star_number').html(count1);
    });

    $('.unstar').bind("click", function() {     // <-- changed to bind
        count1--;
        $('.unstar').hide();

        $('.star_number').html(count1);
    });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; another user posted the same answer a couple of minutes before you. I did vote this up.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so just reverse your logic. Whenever you hide .star, you need to show .unstar, and whenever you hide .unstar, you need to show .star.