# jquery show/hide and counter function for individual entries

Tags: jquery, counter

This is a follow-up to [my question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163201/jquery-counter-uncounter-function). The function adds to a counter and shows information when the star is clicked (and vice versa). Everything works fine.

New challenge: the function applies to individual entries in an activity feed and I'm trying to get it to work for each individual entry. Right now, if I click the star in one entry, the counter increases for all the entries. How can I get the jquery function to apply to each individual entry in the activity feed?

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.unstar').hide();
    var count1=0;

    $('.star').bind("click", function() { 
        if ($('.unstar').is(':hidden')) {
            count1++;
            $('.unstar').show();
            $('.star_number').html(count1);
        }
    });

    $('.unstar').bind("click", function() { 
        count1--;
        $('.unstar').hide();
        $('.star_number').html(count1);
    });    
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j5qAs/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one
It adds a `.star-div` wrapper around star and unstar
It uses HTML data, so you can set a default value
It uses jQuery context in selector (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

http://jsfiddle.net/j5qAs/5/

---

### HTML

```
<span href="" class="star-div" data-count="20">
    <span href="" class="star">
        Star
    </span>&nbsp;
    <span class="star_number"></span> &#183;&nbsp;
    <span class="unstar">Unlike</span> </span> <br /> <span href="" class="star-div" data-count="2">
    <span href="" class="star">
        Star
    </span>&nbsp;
    <span class="star_number"></span> &#183;&nbsp;
    <span class="unstar">Unlike</span> </span>

<br /> <span href="" class="star-div" data-count="12">
    <span href="" class="star">
        Star
    </span>&nbsp;
    <span class="star_number"></span> &#183;&nbsp;
    <span class="unstar">Unlike</span> </span>
```

---

### javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('.unstar').hide();
    //var count1=0;

    $('.star').bind("click", function() { 
        var $starNum = $(this).next('.star_number'); 
        var $unstar = $starNum.next();
        var count = parseInt($starNum.text(), 10);
        if (isNaN(count)) count = 0;
        if ($unstar.is(':hidden')) {
            count++;
            $unstar.show();
            $starNum.html(count);
        }
    });

    $('.unstar').bind("click", function() { 
        var $starNum = $(this).prev();
        var count = parseInt($starNum.text(), 10);
        count--;
        $(this).hide();
        $starNum.html(count);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer--very thorough! Accepted and upvoted.

Comment: @yunzen The js in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j5qAs/5/ and the post is different. And this script doesn't use the .star-div wrapper.

Comment: For anyone else reading this: I used the script from @yunzen's js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j5qAs/5/

Answer (score 1):

Check my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/j5qAs/4/).

Below code assumes that `$('.star').next()` is always `.star_number` and `$('.star_number').next()` is always `.unstar`. If not true, change the .next / .prev accordingly.

```
$(function(){
    $('.unstar').hide();
    //var count1=0;

    $('.star').bind("click", function() {
        var $starNum = $(this).next('.star_number');
        var $unstar = $starNum.next();
        var count = parseInt($starNum.text(), 10);
        if (isNaN(count)) count = 0;
        if ($unstar.is(':hidden')) {
            count++;
            $unstar.show();
            $starNum.html(count);
        }
    });

    $('.unstar').bind("click", function() {
        var $starNum = $(this).prev();
        var count = parseInt($starNum.text(), 10);
        count--;
        $(this).hide();
        $starNum.html(count);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Again, you were just a few minutes behind the first responder. And again, I have upvoted you!

Comment: @chowwy Actually I am not, but whichever answer suits you best, should be voted.

Comment: On my system, when the time showed in minutes, it has his answer as a couple of minutes before yours. But I will keep an eye out for your answers; they are good.